# Example of a Shortest Path Tree for a Directed Graph that contains a directed cycle of negative length

Tags: graph-theory, trees

My colleague says this is possible, but I don't understand how. I know it is necessary for the directed Graph to contain no negative cycles in order to prove that the Shortest Path Tree exists. So I don't see how this example is possible without contradicting the necessary condition. Can somebody give me an example?

Comment: I would advise checking precisely the definitions your friend uses.